# adding of alternative node which contain interger value in give linked list?

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

Hi i wrote a code to add alternative node which contain integer value in single linked list.My code get crash please help me to fix it.

example lets take there are 6 node in singly linked list 3 5 8 6 4 9
then o/p should be  3+8+4 and 5+6+9  and my approach is wrong i guess please help me to fix it .In below code i am returning only one alternative value i.e 3+8+4 ?

```
void add(struct st **ptr)
{
    struct st *curr,*prev;
    curr=*ptr;

    while(curr->next!=NULL)
    {
        if(curr->next->next->data!=NULL) //checking alternative node is present or
            //or not and  to avoid crash
        {

            sum= curr->data  +  curr->next->next->data;
        }

        else
        {
            sum= curr->data;
        }
        curr= curr->next;
    }

    prev=*ptr;

    while(prev->next !=null)
    {
        prev=prev->next;

        if(prev->next->next->data!=NULL)
        {
            sum=prev->data+prev->next->next->data;
        }

        else
        {
            sum=prev->data;
        }
    }

    return sum;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, It is not possible to return twice from a function. You can use call by  reference as an alternative to it. Before the function call you can create two variables for two sums, initialize them to zero and send them as reference.

```
int sum_even = 0; //sum of elements at even position
int sum_odd = 0; //sum of elements at odd position
add(&start, &sum_even, &sum_odd); // call by reference
//sum_even and sum_odd will have the respective sums
```

Now for problem on linked lists it is advisable that you sit with pen and paper and try to trace each line of code you write. Testing boundary conditions is essential.
I have written a possible solution for your problem.

```
void add(struct st **ptr, int *sum_even, int *sum_odd)
{
    struct st *even, *odd;
    even = *ptr;
    if(even->next) odd = even->next;
    else odd = NULL;
    while(even != NULL)
    {
        *sum_even += even->data;
        if(even->next == NULL) break;
        even = even->next->next;
    }
    while(odd != NULL)
    {
        *sum_odd += odd->data;
        if(odd->next == NULL) break;
        odd = odd->next->next;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(curr->next->next->data!=NULL)
```

Here you should also check `curr->next->next` is not `NULL`.
Also, your if condition is also not correct. You should check for `next!=NULL` than `data`.

So update your `if`s to

```
if(curr->next->!=NULL && curr->next->next->data!=NULL)
```

Also, try to use *gdb* or some other debugger to debug and see why your program is crashing and what are the problems.

Comment: how can i return two value in the above code i am returning only 1st alternative number sum.I am supposed to return next alternative number as well ?